# Looking for a Haskell function related to liftA2, but works like <|> from Alternative

Tags: haskell, applicative, category-theory

Consider this `liftA2` function:

```hs
liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b -> Maybe c
liftA2 f Nothing  Nothing  = Nothing
liftA2 f (Just x) Nothing  = Nothing
liftA2 f Nothing  (Just y) = Nothing
liftA2 f (Just x) (Just y) = f x y
```

This is equivalent to the real [`liftA2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-841) function from `Control.Applicative`, but specialized for `Maybe`. (and also `liftM2` from `Control.Monad`)

I'm looking for a cousin of that function, that works like this:

```hs
mystery :: (a -> a -> a) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b -> Maybe c
mystery f Nothing  Nothing  = Nothing
mystery f (Just x) Nothing  = Just x
mystery f Nothing  (Just y) = Just y
mystery f (Just x) (Just y) = Just (f x y)
```

The closest concept I'm aware of is `<|>`, but that [discards the second value](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-897) if there are two, whereas I would rather pass a function to combine them.

What is this mystery function called? What type class does it operate on? What terms can I google to learn more? Thank you!

Comment: `liftA2` has as signature, applied to `Maybe`, `(a -> b -> c) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b -> Maybe c`. Notice that the function works on `a`, and `b`, and not `Maybe a`, etc.

Comment: You seem to want a kind of "monoidal transform", i.e. the same translation which maps `Semigroup m` into `Monoid (Maybe m)`. In this scenario, your `f` is the first  semigroup `<>`. (Well, at least if `f` is associative). I don't know of a name for this, not if it is in the libraries.

Comment: That type for `mystery` doesn't make sense given the implementation. Should the `b` and `c` type variables be `a`s instead?

Comment: @chi I had the same thought too, but I found the type in the libraries, as mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to accept a different type signature, working with a Semigroup instance instead of with an arbitrary function `f`, then what you are looking for is the Option newtype from Data.Semigroup:

```
Prelude Data.Semigroup> Option Nothing <> Option Nothing
Option {getOption = Nothing}
Prelude Data.Semigroup> Option (Just [1]) <> Option Nothing
Option {getOption = Just [1]}
Prelude Data.Semigroup> Option Nothing <> Option (Just [2])
Option {getOption = Just [2]}
Prelude Data.Semigroup> Option (Just [1]) <> Option (Just [2])
Option {getOption = Just [1,2]}
```

For an arbitrary function you need something that is pretty specialized to Maybe - I don't really see how it could work for an arbitrary Applicative, or Alternative.

Comment: I'd like to add that the `Option` newtype is now longer needed if you are targetting GHC 8.4 or higher since the `Monoid` instance for `Maybe` is exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you may be interested in the `Semialign` class from [`Data.Align`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semialign-1.1/docs/Data-Align.html), which offers `zip`-like operations that don't drop missing elements:

```
class Functor f => Semialign f where
  align :: f a -> f b -> f (These a b)
  align = alignWith id

  alignWith :: (These a b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
  alignWith f as bs = f <$> align as bs
```

You can write

```
alignBasic :: Semialign f => (a -> a -> a) -> f a -> f a -> f a
alignBasic f = alignWith $ \case
  This a -> a
  That a -> a
  These a1 a2 -> f a1 a2
-- or just
alignBasic f = alignWith (mergeThese f)
```

Since `Maybe` is an instance of `Semialign`, `alignBasic` can be used at type

```
alignBasic :: (a -> a -> a) -> Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
```

Comment: isn't it `alignWith (these id id f)` or something? --- (`these :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> (a -> b -> c) -> These a b -> c`)

Comment: @WillNess, yes, and it turns out there's even a specialized function, `mergeThese`, for this exact application.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes an extra argument in support of `alignWith` being the `liftA2` analogue you are looking for, [as dfeuer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58775293/2751851).

Using [the monoidal presentation of `Applicative`](http://blog.ezyang.com/2012/08/applicative-functors/)...

```
fzip :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f (a, b)
fzip u v = (,) <$> u <*> v  -- Think of this as a default implementation.
```

... we can do a subtle tweak on `liftA2`:

```
liftA2' :: Applicative f => ((a, b) -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
liftA2' f u v = f <$> fzip u v
```

This variation is relevant here because it translates straightforwardly to `Alternative`, under the [products-to-sums monoidal functor interpretation](http://h2.jaguarpaw.co.uk/posts/alternatives-convert-products-to-sums/):

```
-- fzip analogue. Name borrowed from protolude.
eitherA :: Alternative f => f a -> f b -> f (Either a b)
eitherA u v = (Left <$> u) <|> (Right <$> v)

-- Made-up name.
plusWith :: Alternative f => (Either a b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
plusWith f u v = f <$> eitherA u v
```

`plusWith`, however, isn't helpful in your case. An `Either a b -> c` can't produce a `c` by combining an `a` with a `b`, except by discarding one of them. You'd rather have something that takes a `These a b -> c` argument, as using [`These a b`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-1.0.1/docs/Data-These.html#t:These) can express the both-`a`-and-`b` case. It happens that a `plusWith` that uses `These` instead of `Either` is very much like [`alignWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semialign-1.1/docs/Data-Align.html#v:alignWith):

```
-- Taken from the class definitions:
class Functor f => Semialign f where
    align :: f a -> f b -> f (These a b)
    align = alignWith id

    alignWith :: (These a b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
    alignWith f a b = f <$> align a b

class Semialign f => Align f where
    nil :: f a
```

`Alternative` is a class for monoidal functors from Hask-with-`(,)` to Hask-with-`Either`. Similarly, `Align` is a class for monoidal functors from Hask-with-`(,)` to Hask-with-`These`, only it also has [extra idempotency and commutativity laws](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semialign-1.1/docs/Data-Align.html#t:Semialign) that ensure the unbiased behaviour you are looking for.

---

One aspect of `Align` worth noting is that it is closer to `Alternative` than to `Applicative`. In particular, the identity of the `These` tensor product is `Void` rather than `()`, and accordingly `nil`, the identity of `align`, is an empty structure rather than a singleton. That might come as a surprise, given that `align` and friends offer us greedy zips and zips with padding, and that `zip` is often thought of as an applicative operation. In this context, I feel it might help to mention a fact about [`ZipList`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/8.10.1/docs/html/libraries/base-4.14.0.0/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList). `ZipList` offers a zippy `Applicative` instance for lists in lieu of the default, cartesian product one:

```
GHCi> fzip [1,2] [3,9,27]
[(1,3),(1,9),(1,27),(2,3),(2,9),(2,27)]
GHCi> getZipList $ fzip (ZipList [1,2]) (ZipList [3,9,27])
[(1,3),(2,9)]
```

What is less widely known is that `ZipList` also has a different `Alternative` instance:

```
GHCi> [1,2] <|> [3,9,27]
[1,2,3,9,27]
GHCi> [3,9,27] <|> [1,2]
[3,9,27,1,2]
GHCi> getZipList $ ZipList [1,2] <|> ZipList [3,9,27]
[1,2,27]
GHCi> getZipList $ ZipList [3,9,27] <|> ZipList [1,2]
[3,9,27]
```

Instead of concatenating the lists, it pads the first list with a suffix of the second one to the larger of the two lengths. (It is a fitting instance for the type because it follows the [left distribution law](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia#Laws_6) .) `align` for lists is somewhat similar to `(<|>) @ZipList`, except that it isn't biased towards either list:

```
GHCi> align [1,2] [3,9,27]
[These 1 3,These 2 9,That 27]
GHCi> align [3,9,27] [1,2]
[These 3 1,These 9 2,This 27]
```